# Why does tidycensus get_decennial() fail when used within a function?

Tags: r, tidycensus

I am quite confused as to why this error occurs. I am trying to write a function that passes a character string to `get_decennial()` from the `tidycensus` package but it throws an error.

I am able to successfully run the same code outside the scope of the function. I can't seem to grasp why passing an input to the function makes it fail. Especially, since I am successful in passing in an object to the function already for the `county` parameter (as shown below). Has anyone else encountered anything like this? I think the below example illustrates the issue. I tried copy the output/error from the last call, but I apologize for the low quality formatting in advance.

```
library(tidycensus)
library(dplyr)
census_api_key(Sys.getenv("CENSUS_API_KEY")) # put your census api key here

oregon <- filter(fips_codes, state_name == "Oregon")
oregon_counties <- oregon$county_code  

# this works
why_does_this_work <- "Oregon"

get_decennial(geography = "block group", 
                state = why_does_this_work, 
                variables = "H00010001",
                county = oregon_counties,
                quiet = TRUE)


# why doesn't this work
why_doesnt_this_work <- function(x) {

  get_decennial(geography = "block group", 
                state = x, 
                variables = "H00010001",
                county = oregon_counties,
                quiet = TRUE)
 }

why_doesnt_this_work("Oregon")
```

`Getting data from the 2010 decennial Census`

`Getting data from the 2010 decennial Census` 
 `Getting data from the 2010 decennial Census` 
 `Error : Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector` 
 `In addition: Warning messages:` 
`1: '03' is not a valid FIPS code or state name/abbreviation` 
 
`2: '03' is not a valid FIPS code or state name/abbreviation` 
 
 
 "Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in gather_(data, key_col = compat_as_lazy(enquo(key)), value_col = compat_as_lazy(enquo(value)),  : 
  unused argument (-NAME)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of how R evaluates objects along the hierarchy of environments. 
In other words, there is already an element called "x" in the code of the get_decennial() function. Your custom function why_doesnt_this_work() is evaluated at the same level as get_decennial(). Thus, a same value for at least two elements/objects is appllied to the get_decennial pipeline, breaking things.

To solve the problem, simply rename your custom x to what get_decennial expects, that is "state".

```
why_doesnt_this_work <- function(state) {

  get_decennial(geography = "block group", 
            state = as.character(state), 
            variables = "H00010001",
            county = oregon_counties,
            quiet = TRUE)
  }
why_doesnt_this_work('Oregon') ## Now it works!
```